# Need help designing LiFePO4 BMS disconnect alarm

Tags: solid-state-relay, piezo-buzzer, lifepo4

I need help designing an alarm for a 12v LiFePO4 + BMS system. I am using an off the shelf BMS. The BMS has internal FET switching which may disconnect the battery for a variety of reasons to protect the battery from damage (e.g. over/under volt, low/high temperature, over current). I would like to build a simple buzzer/beeper circuit to provide an audible alarm when the BMS fires its protections. I would like this alarm to be very reliable and have very low power consumption.

Conceptually, I think this can be done using a normally closed (NC) relay driven from B+ and P-. When the BMS fires and goes open-circuit, the relay would close and the beeper would sound. I might power the beeper from the unprotected battery (B+/B-) or a secondary battery.

In order to keep power consumption extremely low, I think I need to use a solid state relay. I gather that's a "form-B" SSR. The beeper will have very low draw - perhaps less than 25mA.

I need help selecting a reliable SSR for this application. And a realiaty check on this design. Is this the way to go, or is there a simpler way to do this.

Thanks!

[image]

**5-Apr-2020**: Expanding the scope a bit... this is for installation on a boat, where there are many "loads". One of those is a large inverter whose DC current is too large to put through the BMS - and will be bypassing the BMS. But the inverter has remote on/off switch terminals. So the BMS can simply command the inverter off when the BMS trips. This would be a NC circuit that needs to go open circuit on a BMS trip. This circuit as well has a very low amperage requirement. So considering these together, when the BMS trips and goes open circuit, I want to close a circuit on a beeper to raise an alarm, and i want to open a circuit on the inverter remote control terminals to shut the inverter down.

**10-Apr-2020**: I've explored @Russel McMahon's solution in Circuit Simulator. I've used 1M resistors for R1 and R2. I added R3 to provide some voltage to drive the MOSFET when the load is disconnected. And moved the opto to reverse it's logic (load off when the BMS trips). This seems to work nicely!

[image] 
[Circuit Simulator](http://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?cct=$%201%200.000005%207.619785657297057%2046%205%2043%0Av%20-80%20384%20-80%20336%200%200%2040%2015%200%200%200.5%0As%20-80%20272%20-80%20160%200%201%20false%0Ar%200%20160%20224%20160%200%200.1%0Ar%20384%20272%20304%20272%200%201000000%0Ar%20464%20320%20464%20384%200%201000000%0Af%20544%20272%20608%20272%2032%201.5%200.02%0Az%20384%20384%20384%20320%202%20default-zener%0A181%20608%20256%20720%20256%200%201775.5251180542402%200.1%209%200.000009999999999999999%200.000009999999999999999%0Av%20720%20384%20720%20304%200%200%2040%209%200%200%200.5%0As%20224%20272%20224%20384%200%201%20false%0Aw%20720%20384%20608%20384%200%0Aw%20384%20272%20464%20272%200%0Aw%20384%20384%20464%20384%200%0Aw%20464%20384%20544%20384%200%0Aw%20384%20384%20224%20384%200%0A370%20224%20160%20224%20272%201%200%0Ar%200%20272%20224%20272%200%201000000%0A370%20-80%200%200%200%201%200%0Ap%20544%20272%20544%20384%201%200%0Aw%20544%20384%20608%20384%200%0A370%20-80%20336%20-80%20272%201%200%0A370%20720%20304%20720%20256%201%200%0Ax%20187%20333%20213%20336%204%2012%20BMS%0Ax%20-169%20367%20-104%20385%204%2012%20LiFePO4%5Cs4S%5C%5Cn10-14.4v%0Aw%20-80%20384%2048%20384%200%0Aw%2048%20384%20224%20384%200%0Ax%2094%20186%20126%20189%204%2012%20Loads%0Aw%200%2032%200%2064%200%0Aw%20224%2064%20224%20160%200%0Ar%200%2064%2080%2064%200%201000%0A407%200%200%2096%200%201%0Ax%20743%20333%20818%20366%204%2012%209v%5CsBatt%5C%5Cn5.5%5CswH%5C%5Cn%3E90k%5Csdays???%0A370%20-80%20160%200%20160%201%200%0A370%20-80%20272%200%20272%201%200%0As%20-80%20160%20-80%2096%200%200%20false%0Av%20224%200%20160%200%200%200%2040%205%200%200%200.5%0Ar%2096%200%20160%200%200%201000%0A370%20224%2032%20224%200%201%200%0A370%20464%20272%20544%20272%201%200%0A370%20608%20288%20608%20384%201%200%0Ap%20-80%2096%2080%2096%201%200%0Aw%20-80%200%20-80%2096%200%0A370%20224%20272%20304%20272%201%200%0A370%20464%20272%20464%20320%201%200%0Ar%2080%2064%20224%2064%200%203000%0Aw%2080%2064%2080%2096%200%0Ax%208%20-33%2095%20-15%204%2012%20Optocoupler%5C%5CnNeeds%5Cs3v%5Cp%5Csdrive%0Ax%20285%20-10%20383%2038%204%2012%20Simulating%5Csremote%5C%5Cninverter%5Cson/off%5C%5Cnopen%5Cscircuit%5Csto%5Csturn%5C%5Cninverter%5Csoff%0Ax%20620%20200%20711%20203%204%2012%20BMS%5CsTrip%5CsBeeper%0A368%20224%20272%20176%20224%200%200%0A368%20-80%20272%20-128%20256%200%200%0AO%2096%2032%20112%20112%200%0Aw%2096%2032%20224%2032%200%0A370%20384%20272%20384%20320%201%200%0Ax%20530%20227%20617%20245%204%2012%20Needs%5Cs3v%5Cp%5Csdrive%5C%5Cnat%5Csgate%0Ax%20-65%20344%20-50%20347%204%2012%20B%5Cp%0Ax%20-64%20376%20-52%20379%204%2012%20B-%0Ax%20201%20312%20213%20315%204%2012%20P-%0Ax%2037%20293%20147%20326%204%2012%20R3.%5CsProvides%5Csvoltage%5C%5Cnto%5CsMOSFET%5Cswhen%5C%5Cnload%5Csis%5Csdisconnected%0Ax%20-72%20214%2015%20217%204%2012%20Load%5Csdisconnect%0Ax%20436%20354%20451%20357%204%2012%20R1%0Ax%20335%20294%20350%20297%204%2012%20R2%0Ao%2051%2064%200%204098%2010%200.1%200%201%0A)

Comment: Zener (which you have retained) does no harm even if their is some very slight leakage, and it protects FET gate against hard overvoltage of transient.

Comment: how low do you need the current consumption to be when the battery is OK? You could just use a standard 12V signal relay which is held on by the battery, then run the buzzer (suggest a piezo element) on the NC contacts. Couldn't be simpler, you can find such a relay with coil resistance of 1k quite easily. 12mA is presumably not going to make much difference on a boat 12V circuit? I'd also suggest a series momentary action switch so that you can test the relay and buzzer once in a while.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve a zero standby-current solution using a MOSFET to drive the beeper.

Voltage from B- to P- is about 0 volts when operational and then changes under disconnect. With either polarity a MOSFET can be biased off when the input is a short circuit and turned on when a voltage exists. Exact details depends on what appears across the BMS when tripped, but whatever it is will "not be a problem".

Powering the beeper from the main battery is possible but would introduce more uncertainties (eg blown internal fuse or link may remove all battery voltage. A separate battery makes the alarm far more fail safe.

Powering the buzzer with eg a 9V Alkaline battery will give 5 to 10 years of standby battery life (zero current) and a 9V Lithium primary battery 10 years +.

If you can report the voltage across the BMS when operating and when tripped it would help. It MAY prove useful to connect a small (high resistance) "load" from B+ to P- (so small a current as to not cause problems) but this is to be determined based on measurements.

Q1: What is the voltage across the BMS (P+ to P-) when operating?

Q2: BMS voltage when tripped?

Q3: Do you want the alarm to sound when the LOAD is removed but the BMS is tripped.?

---

**Example circuit:**

"Lamp" can be buzzer or other annunciator.
Vin is ~0V in normal operation and some positive voltage under alarm condition. As the whole unit "floats" a voltage that goes negative under alarm conditions relative to some reference can be connected "upside down".
If Vin is less than about 12V R2 may not be\ needed but is useful for safety purposes. When equipped RR2 R1 divide Vin down to a suitable value.
Zener Z1 clamps gate voltage to a suitable maximum value - say 12V is OK in most cases.
M1 can be one of many small N Channel MOSFETS.
D1-Q1 form an optocoupler providing isolated alarm notification.

Quiescent current is essentially zero.
If BAT1 is Alkaline a lifetime of 5-10 years is expected.
If BAT1 is Lithium primary a 10+ year lifetime is expected.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=https%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fTsYby.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Hi @Russel McMahon. Thanks responding. I don't yet have the BMS in hand yet - so no answers at the moment. It's on its way from China. ETA hopefully 2 weeks. re Q1, are you asking for voltage drop across the BMS while under load (B- to P-)? or the voltage drop across the load (B+ to P-)? re Q3, yes, I would want the alarm to continue sounding when the load is remote (goes open circuit). i like the idea of powering this from a 9v lithium - and maybe just replacing that every 5 years for good measure.

Comment: _"I would want the alarm to continue sounding when the load is remote (goes open circuit)"_ - Connect the FET Source to B-, Gate to P-, and the input side of R2 to B+. This should pull the Gate high even if the load is open circuit. If quiescent current draw through R2 is too high then increase it to eg. 1M and increase R2 to suit (eg. 470k). Z1 could leak and reduce gate voltage, so remove it and choose a FET with max Gate voltage of +-20V or higher.

Comment: @BruceAbbott - so connect the gate to both P- and center of the R1/R2 divider? That seems to work too. Is a 2N7000 FET suitable for this?

Comment: Yes, Gate to center of R1/R2 and P-. 2N7000 should work OK with R1 = R2 (6V on the Gate).